# How to install NodeJS 6.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed Node.js using the command `sudo apt-get install nodejs`. This is installing Node version 6.5.0. But I have to work on version 6.1.0.

How can I install a specific version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install a specific version of Node.js.

After installing nvm, use this in a terminal:

```
nvm install 6.1.0
```

Then, verify that the correct version has been installed by using `node -V`. Using nvm, you can switch between Node versions trivially easily, which can be very helpful when you're using modules that  require a specific version.

Comment: I was going to type just this - use NVM to manage your npm/node versions and your life will be infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial schould help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Edit:
got this from here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521729